# Column width of a DataGrid in a Windows Mobile

Tags: windows, vb.net, mobile

I'm having a problem in editing the width of my datagridview. It doesn't changed the width. Here's my source code.

```
        oDotNet.SqlDb.strCommand = "SELECT TOP 1 ItemCode, ItemName FROM [" & oAPP.oSQLDatabase & "]..OITM"
        dgMain.DataSource = oDotNet.SqlDb.Ds.Tables(0).DefaultView

        Dim oTableStyle As New DataGridTableStyle
        oTableStyle.MappingName = oDotNet.SqlDb.Ds.Tables(0).DefaultView.GetType().Name
        Dim oTextBoxColumn As New DataGridTextBoxColumn
        oTextBoxColumn.Width = 400
        oTextBoxColumn.MappingName = "ItemName"
        oTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "ItemName"
        oTableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(oTextBoxColumn)
        dgMain.TableStyles.Clear()
        dgMain.TableStyles.Add(oTableStyle)
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove below line and execute it works:

```
  oTableStyle.MappingName = oDotNet.SqlDb.Ds.Tables(0).DefaultView.GetType().Name
```